# How to unpublish a complete website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My client give me his FTP I'm download source code.
Its published.
How can i do changes in code.
My client have not the Unpublished code.
What can i do?

Comment: *"tell me as soon as possible"* ??

Comment: If you mean the site is compiled and you need to make changes to the compiled code, you need to ask your client for the source code. If he doesn't have it, he needs to get it from his original developer. If not possible you can try to decompile with Red Gate .net Reflector

Comment: If you're asking how to make changes to compiled asp.net code...you're out of luck.

Comment: [dotnet dll decompile and change the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388985/dotnet-dll-decompile-and-change-the-code)??

Comment: i'm decompiled the dll but what i change its do not apply in website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to check a few things

1- Check the code and see whether you can find .cs files with you .aspx files. If you can find them then it means that the website was deployed in Debug mode and you can atleast have the code of all the asp.net forms.

And if you cannot find the .cs files then it was deployed in Release mode and you are screwed.

2- Check the debug/release folder of the code and see whether you can find some custom DLL's. (By custom, i mean DLL's that are not from Microsoft and any third party). If you can find some custom DLL's then you cannot do anything because you donot have the code for the DLL's. (So, you do not have the Dll project).

You can still retrieve the code of DLL's by using some tools but that is not recommended.

EDIT:

You cannot get the exact code, but you can get a decompiled version of it.

The most popular (and best) tool is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), but there are also other .Net decompilers (such as [Dis#](http://www.netdecompiler.com/)). You can also decompile the IL using [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which comes bundled with the .Net Framework SDK Tools.

Comment: yes i have the dll in bin folder

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use the tools to get the code.

Comment: i used it but why my changes are not apply on website

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand you ?

Comment: i use the reflector but its give code but what i changes in code that do not apply on design page

Comment: Well you need to rebuild the dll and replace the dlls in the bin folder with new one.

Comment: Yes, client want to change in website but in dll have another important files i need to change in one file only i change with help of reflector but its do not apply in dll/website

Comment: You have  changed the dll code and replaced the dll in the published folder  and still the website is not showing your new change ?

Comment: Yes its do not show the changes.

Comment: i saw your website(http://techroz.com) its nice but i can't explore now.

Comment: Well cannot say anything. Have u placed the dll in release and debug folders ?